# sshd: Why does an exclusion via AllowUsers result in "Permission denied, please try again."

Tags: ssh, authentication

In the end this turned out to be a simple RTFM issue, but one question remains:

If a user is not mentioned in `AllowUsers` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, the resulting `Permission denied...` reply is indistinguishable from a mis-typed password, including the delay of a few seconds. Is this intentional?

It almost looks as if ssh sends mangled data to `PAM` instead of just replying that the user is not allowed to log in via ssh.

Just asking because I spent a few hours looking in all the wrong places (seems like all Linux distros I've been dealing with so far defaulted to allowing any user to log in using ssh).

Comment: "It almost looks as if ssh sends mangled data to PAM" -- that's exactly what it does:
https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/auth-pam.c#L955

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional. The similarity in error messages is designed to help thwart brute-force attacks by not giving you hints about whether it's an invalid user, a non-existent user, or simply an incorrect password.